# get top 1 of navigation property and use as scalar property

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

We have a really ugly database with approx 450 tables, at least as many views, and as many stored procs, and in addition we will be doing a bunch of inline sql conversions that will add to the database complexity.   Client says no changes to db schema are allowed.  In an attempt to reduce the complexity for the development team, we are trying to use EF Code First to Existing Database, following repository and unit of work pattern, to clean up the data model and hide the ugly with mappings, entity splits and table splits.  There are several instances where only the 'current' navigation property matters and I would like to get an ID for it and use it as a scalar property in the of the class.

Something like this:

Claim has a one to many relationship to  claim status but only one status is the current status.  Status has additional related properties.
I want to get the current claims status ID and use it as a scalar property of the claim entity.  The developer could then use this as an FK in order to re-query where necessary instead of having a huge jumble of navigation properties to database views.

```
public class Case
    {
    [Key]
    public int intCaseID { get; set; } // ingCaseID (Primary key)
    public int? intBatchID { get; set; } // intBatchID
    [NotMapped]
    public int intCurrentCaseStatusID {

        get
        { 

            // return the top (1) ID from case status for this claim filtered by any other fields necessary
        }
        set; }

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual ICollection<CaseStatus> CaseStatus { get; set; } //CaseStatus.FK_CaseStatus_Case
```

Is this possible?  Can someone point me in the right direction?  This would go a really long way in cleaning up our model. This is a fairly simple example, as some of our database views and stored procs are doing a great deal more with joins and where clauses. I'm having trouble even coming up with the correct search terms to research this.

Be gentle with your responses please.  This is the first time I've ever posted a question to a forum like this.  :-)  Thanks for any help you can provide.

UPDATE:  I was able to do linq in order to query the collection of casestatuses, but this will only work if I use an AllIncluding from the repo.  Anything else and it throws a null exception because CaseStatus is empty (of course).  This is not a good solution because the plan is to do this to a bunch of navigation properties.  Is there anyway to link a single property to a stored proc without actually bringing the proc in as an entity?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

See if this helps

```
[NotMapped]
public int intCurrentCaseStatusID {

    get
    { 
        var currentCaseStatus CaseStatus.OrderByDescending(c=>c.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentCaseStatus == null) return default(int);

        return currentCaseStatus.CaseStatusId;
    }
}
```

Comment: JC, Thanks for the response.  I probably wasn't clear in my original post, but I am looking for a way to get the currentCaseStatus without including the collection of all CaseStatuses when calling it from the BLL because the current one is really all I care about in this context and the collection of CaseStatuses could be very large. I was looking for a way to give the developer this property for free without needing to use allIncluding(cs=>cs.CaseStatus).  Am I asking too much from EF?]

Comment: My example would only bring back one record. If you look at the SQL generated by EF, you'll see that it uses the TOP and ORDER BY clauses to limit the result set to the most recent record.